# How to get ids from a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do i access ids from a nested resource ?There is no id people_id in`@peoples=@city.peoples`.i get an error `Couldn't find People without an ID`.Thank you in advance.

Models

```
    class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :peoples 
    end

   class People < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :city
   end
```

controller

```
  def show
  @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
  @peoples=@city.peoples
  @people=@peoples.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Routes

```
   resources :city, :people
   resources :cities do
   resources :peoples  
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message refers to model `Deal`, but your example refers to `City` and children  `People`.  Anyhow, each `People` instance in `@Peoples` (or `@city.peoples`) should have its ID attribute available as `id` -- not `people_id`.

Comment: sorry that was copy paste typo.Yes but the thing is it says could not find people without an id which means there is no id in people instance,which makes me think that has something to do with routes

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from this line

```
@people = @peoples.find(params[:id])
```

Are you sure you set `params[:id]`? How are you linking to your show action?

Also I don't think you can call find on the instance variable `@peoples` as I think it is an array, but I could be wrong.